Menu Steals Focus
I'm using Kubuntu 24.04 LTS. Whenever a menu is open, it prevents any other window from taking focus. This is most obvious with the "Focus follows mouse" option, but with "Click to focus" (my preference) it is remarkably annoying. For example, I use alt+middle mouse to move/resize windows, and this will occasionally trigger an app menu. If I moved the window in order to focus on the window behind it, I then have to click twice - once to close the menu, and a second time to focus on the window I want. There are other circumstances in my workflow where it is even more disruptive.
Essentially, open menus act as a modal window, preventing any interaction with anything else until they are closed. I would like them to act optionally, so that I can continue working as if they had never opened (unless I click on them). In other words, I would like the menu to close and my mouse click to register when I click on another application, or even the focused app.
I have tried:

Window activation policy: "Click to focus", "Click to focus (mouse precedence)", "Focus follows mouse",
Focus steeling prevention: "none"

Left click is set to "Activate, raise and pass click"
I'm surprised I can't find this issue online in any forums. Is what I want possible in KDE?
Output of lsb_release -a:
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release:        24.04
Codename:       noble


Just a though, but I don't think this is KDE Plasma specific; eg. I'm using the LXQt desktop currently (Lubuntu) and I see the identical behavior; LXQt is a Qt5 (noble) desktop just as KDE Plasma is.  I've never explored further sorry   (it may also be unrelated to the Qt5 I mention here I realize, but this comment maybe read as blaming, as there is more involved than just the Q toolkit in regards this)

I thought this question would garner more activity than it has. The described behavior introduces a lot of unnecessary clicks and causes numerous mis-clicks and other unwanted behavior. Or do I somehow have a weird configuration that most people don't experience?

"garner more activity"??  Don't forget that 24.04 is using an older KDE Plasma 5 LTS platform, where all KDE development is now on KDE Plasma 6 using Qt6, with the reason for Kubuntu/Ubuntu sticking with Qt5/KDE Plasma 5 explained months prior to 24.04's release. Development software is on the replacement to what you're using, being the final LTS release of KDE Plasma 5 (ie. end of the road for that version)

I get it. I thought I was making two reasonable assumptions though: 1) this has been an issue for more than just Kubuntu 24.04 LTS, and 2) I'm not the only person still using Kubuntu 24.04 LTS. I figure if it's been a long-standing issue, people might comment, or if they like the stability of LTS, they might comment. It doesn't seem unreasonable that there would be a decent number of people who are or have dealt with this issue... but evidence does appear to be contrary to my expectations.
